# How to get tagname of the current selected element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `$('[attribute]')` to select html nodes. When I am using the nodes it would be nice to know which html element was selected.

Pseudo code:

```
$('body').on('click', '[action]', function(){
    var htmlElementName = this.name;

    if(htmlElementName == 'form'){
        return;
    }

            //do stuff

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get the value of a `tagName` property:

```
var htmlElementName = this.tagName;
```

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName

Answer (score 3):

As per the title, in jQuery specifically

```
$(this).prop('tagName');
```

the native version seems simpler

```
this.tagName
```

note that case might vary, so using toLowerCase() is generally a good idea

Comment: According to the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.tagName#Example) the case varies only for HTML and XML: *"In XHTML (or any other XML format), "span" would be alerted. In HTML, "SPAN" would be alerted instead."*. So if the OP works with a proper HTML document the name in capitals should be returned.

Comment: @VisioN - that's why it might vary, I always chain on a toLowerCase() to avoid issues, as I can never remember when it's lowercase and when it's uppercase.

Comment: Interesting that you don't use `toUpperCase()` instead `;)`

Comment: @VisioN - Actually, I've created my own custom `toCamelCase()` that I use `;)`

Comment: BTW did you know that [jQuery has its own implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14345461/1249581) of `toCamelCase`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.tagName`

```
$('body').on('click', '[action]', function(){
    var htmlElementName = this.name;
    var tagName = this.tagName;
    if(htmlElementName == 'form'){
        return;
    }       //do stuff    
});
```

Comment: You see it was so simple that I could not find this. I tried tagname, name, elementname and nodename. Just forgot a capital!

Comment: Yes, it happens sometimes, javascript is case sensitive thats why.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('body').on('click', '[action]', function(e){

    var htmlElementName = $(this).prop("tagName");

});
```