# Fastest way to check if a JS variable starts with a number

Tags: javascript

I am using an object as a hash table and I have stuffed both regular properties and integers as keys into it.

I am now interested in counting the number of keys in this object which are numbers, though obviously a `for (x in obj) { if (typeof x === "number") { ... } }` will not produce the result I want because all keys are strings.

Therefore I determined that it is sufficient for my purposes to assume that if a key's first character is a number then it must be a number so I am not concerned if key "3a" is "wrongly" determined to be a number.

Given this relaxation I think i can just check it like this

```
for (x in obj) {
  var charCode = x.charCodeAt(0);
  if (charCode < 58 && charCode > 47) { // ascii digits check
     ...
  }
}
```

thereby avoiding a regex and `parseInt` and such.

Will this work? `charCodeAt` is JS 1.2 so this should be bullet-proof, yes?

Hint: I would love to see a jsperf comparing my function with what everyone comes up with. :) I'd do it myself but jsperf confuses me

Update: Thanks for starting up the JSPerf, it confirms my hope that the `charCodeAt` function would be executing a very quick piece of code reading out the int value of a character. The other approaches involve parsing.

Comment: Looks good to me. 1.2 was released back in 1997, so unless you're targeting Internet Explorer 3.0, you'll be safe.

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456336/finding-variable-type-in-javascript

Comment: @Ofear It appears you are attempting to give incorrect advice. Read over my second paragraph please

Comment: Do you need to account for negative integers too?  If so, you have one more sign to allow...

Comment: Great point to point out @ScottSauyet! In this particular case I only have positive integers (they are multitouch identifier handles)

Comment: But what's the problem in using `x[0] > -1 && x[0] < 10`?

Comment: @VisioN I don't see a problem with that either. More type coercion than necessary though

Comment: I smell a JSPerf test coming on!  :-)

Comment: @ScottSauyet benchmarks definitely make for the best SO topics

Comment: @StevenLu: I don't have time to create one now.  But I'm curious to see the results if someone does...

Comment: @ScottSauyet, I made one: http://jsperf.com/is-string-a-number - feel free to fork and edit.

Comment: Very nice!  I added a technique that I thought might be relatively quick; it turned out to be the slowest by far!  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why speculate when [you can measure](http://jsperf.com/is-string-a-number). On Chrome, your method appears to be the fastest. The proposed alternatives all come at about 60% behind on my test runs.

Comment: Thanks! Not often you get to see 60M ops/s on JSPerf

Comment: Wow! look at that bar for Firefox 18!! Something tells me the JIT is optimizing something out.

Comment: @StevenLu, yeah, I had to also test for myself, got a very similar result. I'll see if I can change the test cases so that the JIT doesn't drop the code paths as redundant, which I presume is what is happening.

Comment: @StevenLu Once we gained our code in 65M times for Chrome and in 450M times for Firefox after answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218363/detecting-if-anything-on-the-page-is-being-animated.

Comment: @StevenLu either I don't know how to trick the firefox js compiler, or then firefox really is that fast on `charCodeAt`: http://jsperf.com/is-string-a-number/4

Comment: It only really needs to dereference a pointer and spit back the char's int value. I'd expect it to be blisteringly fast. Question would be why is webkit so slow in comparison.

Comment: @StevenLu Suprisingly (or not...) the `charCodeAt` isn't the fastest on IE9 - string comparison is, though not by much, and they're all slow compared to a real browser.

Comment: This is pretty good, my original proposition blows every other approach out of the water. Kinda miffed the question still has no upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt(x, 10)` will correctly parse a leading positive or negative number from a string, so try this:

```
function startsWithNumber(x) {
    return !isNaN(parseInt(x, 10));
}

startsWithNumber('123abc'); // true
startsWithNumber('-123abc'); // true
startsWithNumber('123'); // true
startsWithNumber('-123'); // true
startsWithNumber(123); // true
startsWithNumber(-123); // true
startsWithNumber('abc'); // false
startsWithNumber('-abc'); // false
startsWithNumber('abc123'); // false
startsWithNumber('-abc123'); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is misleading because it is hard to tell this of a *variable*'s name but in the example you're dealing with object properties (which are some kind of variables of course...). In this case, if you only need to know if it *starts* with a number, probably the best choice is `parseInt`. It will return `NaN` for any string that doesn't start with a number.

Comment: Indeed `parseInt` would be a solid choice as well and likely similar in perf to `isNaN`, though it's clear that only the first character ever needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `isNaN(x)` or `isFinite(x)` - see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352577/check-that-variable-is-a-number?rq=1)

Comment: So the question is, are either of those better/faster than a (< 58 && > 47) check

Comment: I would consider it better, because it won't break if sometime later you add the key "123foo"

Comment: This has a different answer than the original solution, although perhaps a better one.  `!isNan('3a') === false`, whereas `originalSolution('3a') === true`.